# Android. WindowManager removeView weird behavior

Tags: java, android

In my application I add through `WindowManager` view with

> type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

with removing it after as user pressed button

> windowManager.removeView(alertView)

In my HTC Incredible S, Nexus 4, Nexus 7 program logic working proper, but in LG-P715 it not working proper. After as I call `windowManager.removeView(alertView)` view is not removed and still stayed on screen and next call `windowManager.removeView(alertView)` crashed my application with `IllegalArgumentException` this means what view already removed.
I don't understand what happend and how I can fix this. 
Please help, I need your advice

> public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>
> ```
>     windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService("window");
>
>     alertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.alert_screen, null);
>
>     Button unlockButton = (Button) alertView.findViewById(R.id.hideButton);
>     unlockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             hide();
>         }
>     });
>
>     param = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
>     param.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
>     param.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
>     param.width  = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
>     param.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
>     param.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
>     param.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
>             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
>             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
>     windowManager.addView(alertView, param);
>
>     return START_NOT_STICKY;
> }
>
> private void hide() {
>     if (windowManager != null) {
>         try {
>             windowManager.removeView(alertView);
>         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
>             Logger.e("IllegalArgumentException in detach window");
>         }
>
>         alertView = null;
>     }
>     stopSelf();
> }
> ```

Comment: not home button, button placed on view

Comment: could you please provide source code ?

Comment: please provide the logcat

Comment: Why you need logcat?? I have no errors

Comment: you said the application is crashing with IllegalArgumentException

Comment: I said `view is not removed and still stayed on screen` and application crashed when I for test trying to remove view again

Comment: @NikedLab add the `View` in `onCreate()` of `Service` and remove it `onDestroy()` as `onStartCommand()` can be called multiple times on each call of `startService()`...

Comment: @Gopal Rao Thank you. But I still don't understand why this code worked on other devices )

Comment: @NikedLab so is your problem solved? and the answer to your question is "It is based on the memory condition. some times System will kill your Service without any prior notice to you on low memory situations and will resumes your Service when memory is available"

Comment: @Gopal Rao Yes, problem solved, I think too it is low memory issue